# Using `WITH` or `MATCH` clause while extracting paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Before I explain the problem I am facing, I think it would be better if I explain the structure of my graph database a bit. Following are the Nodes, Relationships and Properties in my `neo4j` graph database:

## Nodes:

- User
- Email
- Phone
- Book
- BlogPost

## Relationships:

- HAS (used as : ***user -[:HAS]-> (e:Email|Phone)***)
- READ (used as : ***user - [:READ] -> (b:Book|BlogPost)***)
- WROTE (used as: ***user - [:WROTE] -> (b:Book|BlogPost)***)

## Properties:

- uid (associated with nodes User, Book, BlogPost, Email, Phone)
- name (associated with node User)
- title (associated with nodes Book, BlogPost)
- email (associated with node Email)
- phone (associeated with node Phone)

Before I actually put up my question I would like to state that I am pretty new to the neo4j technology so I do understand that solution to my problem might be basic.

#### What I am trying to achieve ?

I want to get all the shortest paths between two users and then for each node between those two users in a path I would like to get:

- The email address and/or phone number if the node is a User node.
- Title of the node if it's a Book or a BlogPost node.

#### Where am I stuck ?

I can get the paths using the following cypher query:

```
match (u1: User {uid: '0001'}),
(u2: User{uid: '0002'}),
paths = allShortestPaths((u1)-[*..4]-(u2))
return paths
```

After getting the paths I can get the properties of the nodes, relationships in the path using the `extract`, `nodes`, `relationships` functions if I ammend the above query as follows:

```
match (u1: User {uid: '0001'}),
(u2: User{uid: '0002'}),
paths= allShortestPaths((u1)-[*..4]-(u2))
with extract(n in nodes(paths) | [n.name]) as nds,
extract(r in relationships(paths)| [type(r)]) as rels
return nds,rels
```

#### The problem

But what I really want to get is the `email` and `phone` properties off `Email` and `Phone` nodes that are connected to any nodes within a given path.

I have gone through the [official documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html) and a lot of blog posts but could not find any solution or a similar problem for that matter.

How can I achieve the above mentioned ?

**PS: I would like to achieve this in a single query**

Thanks

Comment: When you say you want the email addresses of the users, are you talking about of the interior nodes on the shortest path, or are you talking about the email of `u1` and `u2`?

Comment: I mean the `email` & `phone` of the interior nodes if the interior node is a `User` node or `title` of the interior node if the interior node is `Book` or `BlogPost` node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this meet your needs?

**Major edits below:**

In the return statement below:

- Get the list of nodes in the path excluding the first and last nodes
- Use labels to inspect only user, book and blog posts
- Filter out the intermediate user nodes into one collection
- Filter out the intermediate book/blog posts and extract the titles into another collection
- Iterate over the intermediate user nodes to find the associated email and or phone nodes (credit @FrobberOfBits)

Here is the cypher:

```
// match the user nodes and the shortest intermediate paths between them
match (u1:User {uid: '0001'})
, (u2:User {uid: '0002'})
, path = allShortestPaths((u1)-[*..4]-(u2))
// filter out the intermediate user nodes into one collection
with filter(n IN nodes(path)[1..length(nodes(path))-1] 
     where any(x in labels(n) where x = 'User'))
     as intermediate_users
// filter out the intermediate book titles into another collection
   , [n IN nodes(path)[1..length(nodes(path))-1] 
     where any(x in labels(n) where x in ['Book','BlogPost']) 
     | n.title ] 
     as intermediate_books_posts
// iterate through the intermediate user nodes
// and optionally match email and phone nodes
unwind intermediate_users as u
optional match (e:Email)<--u-->(p:Phone)
return u.name, e.address, p.number, intermediate_books_posts
```

Comment: I think this should work for OP -- I would also suggest a slight modification that would be possible.  Using `filter` you can build a list of only the `User` nodes, put that in a `WITH` block and then effectively use a sub-query to branch out from there.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, @Dave : Thank you for your time, But the above query returns null for any `email`, `phone` or `Title` value. I think the problem is `x in labels(n)` we are trying to get the labels of the intermediary nodes where as `Email`, `Phone` are separate nodes with `email` and `phone` labels.

Comment: @Amyth - apologies, apparently I cannot read.  Even after Frobber's comments i still missed the proverbial boat.  I will tidy that up for you in a minute.

Comment: @DaveBennett Thanks for taking the time to update this. That definitely does give me the `email` and `phone` properties from the nodes. :)